# Reserve and zero fill system memory region for a PCIE device in driver

Tags: kernel, drivers, memory, pci

I have a PCIE device that requires a (physically contiguous) **scratch memory region** to be allocated in system RAM. The problem arose from its size: it has to be **16 MiB**.

I've been searching for a while but none of the methods described here is capable to allocate such a large block of memory: https://kernelnewbies.org/KernelMemoryAllocation

As a temporary workaround I tried reserving memory with `memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]` kernel command line option but the region reserved this way cannot be mapped into virtual address space and I need to **zero fill** it before handing it over to the device.

I'm looking for a method that:

1. is capable of allocating 16 MiB of contiguous physical memory
2. does not require additional kernel cmd line options nor kernel recompilation
3. the allocated memory can be mapped into virtual address space and thus can be zero filled